# python iterate over dynamically allocated Cython array

Tags: python, c, cython, dynamic-memory-allocation, custom-data-type

I'm writing a python wrapper to a C class and I'm allocating memory using PyMem_Malloc as explained [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html)

```
cdef class SomeMemory:

    cdef double* data

    def __cinit__(self, size_t number):
        # allocate some memory (uninitialised, may contain arbitrary data)
        self.data = <my_data_t*> PyMem_Malloc(number * sizeof(my_data_t))
        if not self.data:
            raise MemoryError()
```

Then I import and use the class in another script using:

```
import SomeMemory

sm = SomeMemory(10)
```

I now would like to access the elements of self.data but I encounter 2 problems

1. if I type self.data and hit enter, the ipython kernel crashes
2. if I try to loop on self data

like:

```
for p in self.data:
    print p
```

I get an error that self.data is not iterable.

How can I access self.data? Do I need to cast the elements to my_data_t first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Heavily edited in light of the updated question)

So - my understanding is that `self.data` needs to be declared as public to access it from Python:

```
cdef class SomeMemory:   
    cdef public double* data
    # also make sure you define __dealloc__ to remove the data
```

However, that doesn't seem to be enforced here.

However, your real problems are that Python doesn't know what to do with an object of type `double *`. It's certainly never going to be iterable because the information about when to stop is simply not stored (so it will always go off the end.

There are a range of better alternatives:

- you store your data as a Python array (see http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/array.html for a guide). You have quick access to the raw c pointer from within Cython if you want, but also Python knows what to do with it

Code follows

```
from cpython cimport array as c_array
from array import array

cdef class SomeMemory:
   cdef c_array.array data

   def __cinit__(self, size_t number):
      self.data = array('d', some initial value goes here)
```

- You store your data as a numpy array. This is possibly slightly more complicated, but has much the same advantages. I won't give an example, but it's easier to find.
- You use Cython's typed memory view: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html. The advantage of this is that it lets you control the memory management yourself (if that's **absolutely** important to you). However, I'm not 100% sure that you can access them cleanly in Python (too lazy to test!)
- You wrap the data in your own class implementing `__getitem__` and `__len__` so it can be used as an iterator. This is likely more trouble that it's worth.

I recommend the first option, unless you have good reason for one of the others.

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain well. I meant to say that the attribute self.data doesn't seem to be visible outside

Comment: I've changed my answer to match the changed question... Hopefully it's more useful now

Comment: Thanks a lot for the lengthy explanation!

Comment: I didn't know about declaring self.data as public, that will solve part of the issue. Thanks! As to your second point, I cannot just use a python array because my_data_t is actually a struct in my C code, not a standard data type. I guess implementing a class wrapper is the only option in this case?

Comment: (Deleted a couple of wrong comments.) Yes, it looks like you will need to implement a small wrapper class containing the basic iteration functions. [I think memoryviews are quite restricted as to what types they can accept.]